# IOS changes the SNMPv3 engineId

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, snmp

I have encountered a very strange problem when configuring remote target engineId on a Catalyst 3750 switch. The switch changes the engineId, it puts a zero between the two last digits. As shown below it changes ...e166 to ...e1606. I have tried with removing the user, rebooting the switch and re-adding the user but the switch changes the engineId every time. I have configured tens of switches in the exact same way and has never come across this problem before. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

```
sw21(config)#snmp-server engineID remote 10.1.9.6 udp-port 162 b7a9d3ca99325e6b5fb2894a500e166

sw21#show snmp user
User name: trap
Engine ID: B7A9D3CA99325E6B5FB2894A500E1606
storage-type: nonvolatile        active
Authentication Protocol: SHA
Privacy Protocol: None
Group-name: sys

sw21#show version
....
Switch Ports Model              SW Version            SW Image
------ ----- -----              ----------            ----------
*    1 30    WS-C3750X-24       12.2(55)SE5           C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M
     2 30    WS-C3750X-24       12.2(55)SE5           C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cisco IOS padded the last 8-bits because you apparently left a digit off to make it a legitimate value... 31 characters isn't a valid hex number

```
[mpenning@some_machine ~]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013, 00:00:18)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> this_str = "b7a9d3ca99325e6b5fb2894a500e166"
>>> len(this_str)
31
>>>
```